# Bootstrap 4: Remove padding-right last grid element on line

Tags: grid, bootstrap-4

How to remove (CSS only) padding in last element on line?
If using with out "no-gutters": https://www.codeply.com/go/p5kwypnNAw
Is it possible to make pure css beauty grid?

```
<div class="container" style="background: yellow;">
  <div class="row text-center text-lg-left no-gutters">
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mr-2 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mr-2 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mr-2 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mr-2 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mr-2 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mr-2 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mr-2 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mr-2 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mr-2 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mr-2 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mr-2 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-xs-6">
      <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mr-2 h-100">
        <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Example with no-gutters you can see there:
https://www.codeply.com/go/SM8kOTGbM5
Main container have yellow background, so you can see addition padding on last right elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: The solution in your case is to replace all instances of the `mr-2` class with `mx-1`.

`mr-2` means: "margin-right 2 units". `mx-1` means: "1 unit horizontal margin (on both sides)".

Here's the working code (click the "run code snippet" button below and expand to full page):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container px-0" style="background: yellow;">
    <div class="row text-center text-lg-left no-gutters">
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
            <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mx-1 h-100">
                <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
            <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mx-1 h-100">
                <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
            <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mx-1 h-100">
                <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
            <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mx-1 h-100">
                <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
            <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mx-1 h-100">
                <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
            <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mx-1 h-100">
                <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
            <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mx-1 h-100">
                <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
            <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mx-1 h-100">
                <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
            <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mx-1 h-100">
                <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
            <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mx-1 h-100">
                <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
            <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mx-1 h-100">
                <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-6">
            <a href="#" class="d-block mb-2 mx-1 h-100">
                <img class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://placehold.it/600x600">
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<br><br><br><br>


<div class="container">
    <div class="row mt-5 justify-content-center">
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.netflix.com/fr/">
               <img src="https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/metro-ui-dock-icon-set--icons-by-dakirby/256/Netflix.png" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="card card-custom mx-2 mb-3">
            <a href="https://www.hulu.com">
               <img src="https://apprecs.com/ios-meta/app-icons/256/376510438.jpg" alt="" class="card-img">
           </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Updated my code snippet again replacing all instances of `col-xs-6` with `col-6` because the `col-xs-*` class doesn't exist in Bootstrap 4. You should use the `col-*` class instead.

Comment: Thank you for answer! Is it possible to remove left and right paddings? http://s9.uploads.ru/d/MboSc.jpg

Comment: Do you want to remove them completely?

Comment: I've added the `px-0` class to the container. Check my updated code snippet. Is that what you want?

Comment: Remove this padding (from left and right colums) ... but i think this is not pissible....? http://s7.uploads.ru/d/4weKb.jpg

Comment: Do you want to have any spacing between the individual images?

Comment: That margin now is coming from the `mx-1` class on the images. If you want the large image above to appear flush with the images below, add the `mx-1` to the large image above.

Comment: Spacing betwiin images - OK, very good, but col's into left column have ml-1 and right colulmn have mr-1 (thats smaller that another content above). But i think this is not possbile to remove ml-1 from items into left columns and mr-1 to items into right columns

Comment: Yes, to keep things responsive you need the `mx-1` class. But if you add the same class to the large image above, then both will be flush i.e. it will look good.

Answer (score 0):

For Removing padding: Just try this class P*-0 (*- x,y,l,r)

x- Xaxis

y- yasis

l- Left

r - Right

For eg: am going to remove padding on right so

HTML:

```
<div class="pr-0">
----
----
----
</div>
```

or by css:

```
div:last-child {
padding-right:0px;
}
```

replace div with your respective class

Comment: Hi, this is for last element, but not last on 'line'